# Повернуть текст внутри TextBox

Tags: xaml, wpf

Возможно ли повернуть текст внутри элемента TextBox в xaml?

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Но такое решение не подходит. Буду вставлять label в элемент.

Answer (score 4):

Могу посоветовать вот это:

```
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="23" Margin="130,140,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="TextBox" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="120">
        <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
        </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBox>
```

Не уверен, что это то, что  вы ищете, с другой стороны, не уверен, что искомое вами вообще имеет смысл - текст в таком случае должен обрезаться краями текстбокса

Comment: Вот хороший пример по теме: http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/03/211105.html

Comment: Да, это не то. Нужно повернуть только текст. Рамка вокруг должна быть обычной, не повёрнутой.

Comment: @xaml извините, а какой в этом смысл? Для чего это вообще?

Comment: нужно сделать рамку, а в ней повёрнутый текст.

Comment: боюсь, вы слишком много (причем, неоправданно) хотите от простого текстбокса

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно повернуть *только текст*, возникают проблемы: как должно происходить обтекание текста?

Попробуйте такую вариацию на тему решения [[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild), может быть, вам подойдёт:

```
<Grid TextBlock.FontSize="18pt" Height="200" Width="200">

    <!-- this one makes the outer border -->
    <TextBox Focusable="False"/>

    <!-- this one eats the clicks -->
    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>

    <TextBox BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" ClipToBounds="False">
        <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
        </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
        Test, more test, even bigger test, huge test, lots of text here
    </TextBox>

</Grid>
```