# xml в wpf - задать свойства другого объекта текущему?

Tags: c#, wpf

Допустим у меня есть

```
  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">dock menu</Button>
```

и я хочу у него развернуть текст на 90 градусов -т.е не саму кнопку а именно текст внутри нее. Но как я понял - свойство `TextBlock` - у кнопки не обладает таким функционалом.
Тогда как было сказано вот в этом ответе на SO - [Повернуть текст внутри TextBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/244771/203448)

я решил создать отдельно `TextBlock` -  развернуть текст в нем, а затем уже этот готовый `TextBox` присвоить в качестве значения для `TextBlock` - кнопки.
На SO - также есть и пример [привязки одного объекта -другому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/375078/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-attached-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA-dependency-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)

создал кнопку - как новый объект: - с оглядкой на первую ссылку мной приведенную.

```
TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
txt.Focusable = false;
txt.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
txt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
txt.ClipToBounds = false;
txt.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(45);
BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
txt.Text = "right panel";`
```

и теперь в кнопке :

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextBlock.  >dock menu</Button>
```

обращаясь к ее `TextBlock.` - *как мне присвоить в качестве значения созданный экземпляр textbox?*

Comment: `я хочу у него развернуть текст на 90 градусов -т.е не саму кнопку а именно текст внутри нее` а чем вас вариант с `RotateTransform` не устроил?

Comment: т.е так что ли 
  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" RotateTransform =""  ?

Comment: Ошибка  Не удалось найти свойство "RotateTransform" в типе "Button". WpfVideoPlayer

Comment: Привел пример кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того что бы повернуть контент внутри кнопки используйте трансформации, например `RotateTransform`.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button Background="Yellow"
            Content="Кнопка">
        <Button.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </Button.LayoutTransform>
    </Button>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это называется `Attached Properties`. Засетать:

```
TextBlock.<Свойство>(txt, <Значение>);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду  разбираться!

Comment: @BadCats обновил ответ, проверьте работает ли.

Comment: TextBlock.LayoutTransform(txt, rotateTransform); -  
Ошибка CS1955 Невызываемый член "FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform" не может использоваться как метод.